# How to scrape and merge visible and hidden data from table with BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to obtain on a single DataFrame all the different tables from each company scraping this web page:

https://rk.americaeconomia.com/display/embed/500-latam/2021

or

https://www.americaeconomia.com/negocios-industrias/estas-son-las-500-mayores-empresas-de-america-latina-2021

It has been very difficult to find a solution.

Comment: You can use `.dataRow td` as the CSS selector if you are trying with bs4

Comment: Noticed your comment - Could you provide some more details and an expected output to clairify for all - Would be great, Thanks

Comment: Hi all! The idea is to generate a DataFrame with the Company name adding columns with all the data that appear in the table of each company.

Comment: @CarlosAlbertoSpoererRuiz --- Not the expected Input --- Good answers require good questions, please help make your problem understandable to all by improving your question. This means in general, the existing code and the expected result should be presented as text. Also take a minute to read [ask] Would be great to read good written questions in future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Situation

There are two different types of `<tr>` one with data and another with extra data corresponding to the first one we have to bring them together. Another point is that extra data is not stored in common table structure

#### How to achieve?

Each combination of data and extra data has to be joined to a single row - There are many options to do so, this approach deals with dataframes. Joined dataframes are stored in a list and would be concatenated after iterating has finished.

```
data = []
for row in soup.select('#awesomeTable tbody tr.extraDataRow'):

    df = pd.DataFrame([list(row.find_previous('tr').stripped_strings)], columns=list(soup.select_one('#awesomeTable tr').stripped_strings))
    df = df.join(pd.DataFrame(dict([list(x.stripped_strings) for x in row.select('p')]), index=df.index))
    data.append(df)


df = pd.concat(data)
```

#### Example

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.110 Safari/537.36'}
r = requests.get('https://rk.americaeconomia.com/display/embed/500-latam/2021',headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,'lxml')
data = []
for row in soup.select('#awesomeTable tbody tr.extraDataRow'):
   
    df = pd.DataFrame([list(row.find_previous('tr').stripped_strings)], columns=list(soup.select_one('#awesomeTable tr').stripped_strings))
    df = df.join(pd.DataFrame(dict([list(x.stripped_strings) for x in row.select('p')]), index=df.index))
    data.append(df)


df = pd.concat(data)
```

#### Output

| RK 2021 | EMPRESA | PAÍS | RK 2020* | RK 2019 | SECTOR / RUBRO | VENTAS 2020 US$ Millones | VENTAS 2019 US$ Millones | VARIACIÓN VENTAS 20/19 (%) | UTILIDAD NETA 2020 US$ Millones | UTILIDAD NETA 2019 US$ Millones | VARIACIÓN UTILIDAD 20/19 (%) | EBITDA 2020 US$ Millones | EBITDA 2019 US$ Millones | VARIACIÓN EBITDA 20/19 (%) | ACTIVO TOTAL 2020 US$ Millones | PATRIMONIO NETO 2020 US$ Millones | EMPLEADOS 2020 | EMPLEADOS 2019 | ROA (%) 2020 | ROE (%) 2020 | MARGEN NETO (%) 2020 | Presencia EN BOLSA | SITIO WEB (www.) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | PETROBRAS | BRA | 1 | 1 | Petróleo/Gas | 53,282.0 | 76,746.8 | -30.6 | 1,392.0 | 10,191.7 | -86.3 | 21,777.0 | 35,461.8 | -38.6 | 190,107.6 | 59,905.7 | N.D. | 58,513 | 0.7 | 2.3 | 2.6 | Sí | petrobras.com |
| 2 | JBS | BRA | 4 | 4 | Alimentos | 52,916.8 | 51,933.1 | 1.9 | 900.5 | 1,540.9 | -41.6 | 5,539.7 | 5,018.0 | 10.4 | 31,536.7 | 8,383.6 | N.D. | 234,192 | 2.9 | 10.7 | 1.7 | Sí | jbs.com.br |
| 3 | AMÉRICA MÓVIL | MX | 3 | 3 | Telecomunicaciones | 51,352.7 | 53,288.7 | -3.6 | 2,366.0 | 3,582.9 | -34 | 16,644.7 | 16,597.6 | 0.3 | 82,064.9 | 15,913.4 | 186,851 | 191,523 | 2.9 | 14.9 | 4.6 | Sí | americamovil.com |
| 4 | PEMEX | MX | 2 | 2 | Petróleo/Gas | 44,676.3 | 72,837.4 | -38.7 | -22,520.7 | -18,042.9 | 24.8 | 4,779.8 | 9,465.4 | -49.5 | 95,527.7 | -122,327.0 | N.D. | 156,614 | -23.6 | 18.4 | -50.4 | No | pemex.com |
| 5 | VALE | BRA | 5 | 5 | Minería | 40,838.3 | 37,743.0 | 8.2 | 5,231.4 | -1,694.0 | -408.8 | 14,527.9 | 4,995.8 | 190.8 | 92,054.2 | 34,845.2 | N.D. | 71,149 | 5.7 | 15 | 12.8 | Sí | vale.com |